# arc diff --update always create new review

Tags: phabricator

I download code from Gitlab, then create a new branch, update some files and create a review. Then I add a file, execute `arc diff --allow-untracked`, it reports `Usage Exception: There are several revisions which match the working copy:`. I execute `arc diff --allow-untracked --update D75` to update the existing review, but it creates a new review. 
`Linting...
    No lint engine configured for this project.
    Running unit tests...
    No unit test engine is configured for this project.
    SKIP STAGING  No staging area is configured for this repository.
    Updating commit message...
    Created a new Differential revision:
        Revision URI: http://codereview.domain.com/D76`

I try many times but it always creates a new revision. How to use `arc diff --update`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `--update` but you do need to specify the base of your change, so to update the revision associated with the current HEAD, try the following:

> `arc diff`***`HEAD^`***

If you've got two commits then you need to use ***`HEAD^^`***.

To update everything on the current branch:

> `arc diff`***`parent-branch`***

So assuming your current branch was branched from master:

> `arc diff`***`master`***

The arcanist documentation covers this topic in detail, so for a more complete understanding of how `arc diff` decides which commits to submit, read [Arcanist User Guide: Commit Ranges](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_commit_ranges/).

Comment: Yes, I use `arc diff master` to diff two branches, but it reports there are several revisions which match the working copy, it needs to specify an existing review to update.